# Workflow to change a column value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I created a workflow that will email the creator after 6 months, if their content hasn't been updated.

But is it possible to then change the value of a column two weeks later if that content still has not been updated?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a Pause action in sharepoint designer workflow that allows you to do this. In your email step, once that is done, pause the workflow for 14 days and then the next action would be Set Field/Update Field to (your value)